# Menu in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

When I installed WordPress I had a home menu. While editing, I added a menu item to the menu but my home menu item disappeared.

I don't know what's going on. How do I add the home menu item which links to homepage back?

Comment: I have not modified in code. I am using typedbased theme. All I did is from admin panel.Any idea where i did wrong?

Comment: Will the home menu item come back if you remove the menu item that you have just added? Could it be only some css problems?

Comment: i tried removing the newly added menu item. But home menu item is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your home item would have disappeared after adding another item, but make sure your theme is using wp_page_menu():

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_page_menu

This carries the benefit of listing your "Home" along with your other pages.

Comment: It was displying previously.So, i think there should not be problem in the code(post-template.php). Now i added a page to menu as Home. But i need to link it to home page. how can i do that.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the line in the header.php

> wp_page_menu( 'show_home=1');

reference in the codex : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_page_menu

Answer (score 0):

If you have already added Home as menu, then copy the content of `index.php` into your `Home.php` (create this empty file in your theme) file.

Then run and check the home page.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1.** For linking your home page, create `index.php` as template file for home like the code below:

Use these codes if you're using custom theme(theme created by yourself in themes folder of wp-content other than twentyelevan, twentyten and so on.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: home
 *
 * Selectable from a dropdown menu on the edit page screen.
 */
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
// whatever body code u need,u can include it here.


<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <div class="post-header">
       <!-- <div class="date"><?php the_time( 'M j y' ); ?></div>-->
       <!-- <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent 
           Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>-->
       <!-- <div class="author"><?php the_author(); ?></div>-->
    </div><!--end post header-->
    <div class="entry clear">
    <?php if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
       <!-- <?php edit_post_link(); ?>-->
    <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
    </div><!--end entry-->
    <div class="post-footer">
    <!-- <div class="comments"><?php comments_popup_link( 'Leave a Comment', '1 
        Comment', '% Comments' ); ?></div>-->    
    </div><!--end post footer-->
  </div><!--end post-->
<?php endwhile; /* rewind or continue if all posts have been fetched */ ?>
  <div class="navigation index">
    <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older Entries' ); ?></div>
    <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' ); ?></div>
  </div><!--end navigation-->
<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>


    <div id="slider">
    <?php
    $tmp = $wp_query;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=5&category_name=featured');
    if(have_posts()) :
        while(have_posts()) :
        the_post();
    ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php 
            the_post_thumbnail('nivothumb'); ?></a>
    <?php
        endwhile;
    endif;
    $wp_query = $tmp;
    ?>
    </div><!-- close #slider -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Or, if you're using wordpress builtin themes, then use these codes:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: onebyone
 *
 * Selectable from a dropdown menu on the edit page screen.
 */
?>
<html>
  // whatever body code u need,u can include it here.
</html>
```

**Step 2.** Then open the home page in wordpress, Pages -> All pages, click edit.

**Step 3.** In edit page of home, in the right side you will see Dropdown named Template. Click the 
dropdown, there you will see your template name as home select it and then click update 
button.

**Step 4.** Then,On top left side corner,click your website or blog name and visit the website or 
blog to check your home page by clicking on it.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have a link to your site?

It may be as simple as checking a box. OR, you can create a custom menu.